# String Insertion Sort program

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting

I am just starting to lean C so I don't know it very well. The program we are given tells us to write an Insertion Sort program that takes 20 strings seperated by space and sorts then alphabetically and prints them out in order. This is confusing me greatly since C doesn't have a String data type (at least to my knowledge). Aren't Strings just character arrays? Here is what I got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_STRINGS 20

void InsertionSort(char list[]);

void main()
{
    int index;
    char strings[MAX_STRINGS];

    /* Get input */
    printf("Enter %s strings.\n", MAX_STRINGS);
    for (index = 0; index < MAX_STRINGS; index++)
    {
        char tempString[100];
        printf("Input string %d : ", index);
        scanf("%s", &tempString[0]);
        strings[index] = tempString;
    }

    InsertionSort(strings);

    printf("\nThe input set, in alphabetical order:\n");
    for (index = 0; index < MAX_STRINGS; index++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", strings[index]);
    }
}

void InsertionSort(char list[])
{
    int unsorted;
    int sorted;
    char unsortedItem;

    for(unsorted = 1; unsorted < MAX_STRINGS; unsorted++)
    {
        unsortedItem = list[unsorted];

        for (sorted = unsorted - 1; (sorted >= 0) && (list[sorted] >  unsortedItem); sorted--)
        {
            list[sorted + 1] = list[sorted];
        }
        list[sorted + 1] = unsortedItem;
    }
}
```

I am completely new to C and C syntax and I find it very confusing. This program is not working correctly. What it is doing is it allows me to enter 20 strings, but then nothing is sorted and it prints out nothing. Any idea on how to fix that? Also, is there any idea to how I can get it to where I type a single sentence and the each string is separated by white space? For example if I type, "I am learning how to program in C and right now I do not like it." that would give me 16 strings. "I", "am", "learning", etc. Thanks.

Comment: [What is the proper declaration of main?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main)

Comment: Well, on some platforms an executable can only return exit codes between 0 and 255, so char is fitting ;-)

Comment: There are enough different things wrong with this that I don't think we can usefully help you.  You need a one-on-one coaching session.  Please take this question to whoever is teaching you the language.

Comment: "Aren't Strings just character arrays?". No, strings are char arrays **terminated with a '\0' character**. This is a very important distinction; if you forget the end delimiter, it will break things.

Comment: please check my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583221/sort-words-alphabeticaly-in-c/33583576#33583576

Comment: I'll give one hint, though: You're absolutely right, C does not have strings.  It only has arrays of characters.  So, if you want to sort twenty strings, that means you need *twenty arrays of characters*.  To do that, you could make an array *of* arrays.  Yes, that's allowed.

Comment: `strings` in not an array of string in your code, it is a just an array of characters, which is basically a string. So you're passing a single string to `InsertionSort` function.

Comment: @zwol - Okay so I need to make a `char stringArray[20]` where each one of the 20 elements is itself a `char word[]`? Something like that?

Comment: `printf("%s\n", strings[index]);` This is wrong for 2 reasons. `strings` is a char array, so `strings[index]` is a char, not a string. Also, you should cast pointers to void* when you pass them into printf; it's a portability issue, so it will work on your system, but it may not work on every system, otherwise.

Comment: @GenericUser01 Something like that, yes, but not exactly that.  Further hint: `[x][y]`.

Comment: @GenericUser01 no, you need `char *StringArray[20]`. Arrays are effectively just pointers, so you need an array of 20 pointers to store the 20 char arrays. Note that you must allocate memory individually to all 20 of these arrays though.

Comment: @BobbySacamano - That's right, because the * signals that were pointing to the first element of the array, correct?

Comment: @zwol - `[x] [y]` so a two-dimensional array?

Comment: @GenericUser01 The * indicates that the variable is a pointer, when used in a declaration; it means something else in an expression. Postfix operators execute before prefix operators, so `char *StringArray[20]` is declared as an array of length 20, each element is a pointer. you'd access each string by `StringArray[i]` and access an element in that string by `StringArray[i][j]`. When you declare a pointer, no memory is allocated yet (unlike an array), so you need to give it some memory before you can write to it.

Comment: Just noticed this, it should really be `int main(void)` instead of `void main()`.

Answer (score 4):

A few problems with the original code:

1) You cannot copy strings using `=`; use [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) for that (using `=` only assigns *pointers*).

2) A string is an array of chars; therefore an array of strings is an array of arrays of chars (so your `InsertionSort` signature is wrong). Note that C strings are null terminated, which simply means that a byte with the value of 0 signifies the end of a string (this is very important, if you forget everything else, remember this).

3) `%s` expects a `char*`; this line produces UB: `printf("Enter %s strings.\n", MAX_STRINGS);`. What you want is `%d` instead (read up on `printf` format specifiers).

4) You can't compare strings using normal arithmetic operators; those compare pointers. You need to use [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).

5) Your implementation of the insertion sort algorithm was wrong.

6) There are a few versions of `main` declarations allowed by the standard, and `char main` isn't one of them. In this case just use `int main`.

Here is a fixed version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_STRINGS 20
#define MAX_STRING_LEN 200

void InsertionSort(char list[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_LEN]);

int main()
{
    int index;
    char strings[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_LEN];

    /* Get input */
    printf("Enter %d strings.\n", MAX_STRINGS);
    for (index = 0; index < MAX_STRINGS; index++)
    {
        printf("Input string %d : ", index);
        scanf("%199s", strings[index]);     // limit the width so we don't go past the buffer
        strings[index][sizeof(strings[index]) - 1] = '\0';
    }

    InsertionSort(strings);

    printf("\nThe input set, in alphabetical order:\n");
    for (index = 0; index < MAX_STRINGS; index++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", strings[index]);
    }
}

void InsertionSort(char list[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_LEN])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < MAX_STRINGS; i++)
    {
        int j = i;

        while (j > 0 && strcmp(list[j - 1], list[j]) > 0)
        {
            char tmp[MAX_STRING_LEN];
            strncpy(tmp, list[j - 1], sizeof(tmp) - 1);
            tmp[sizeof(tmp) - 1] = '\0';

            strncpy(list[j - 1], list[j], sizeof(list[j - 1]) - 1);
            list[j - 1][sizeof(list[j - 1]) - 1] = '\0';

            strncpy(list[j], tmp, sizeof(list[j]));
            list[j][sizeof(list[j]) - 1] = '\0';

            --j;
        }
    }
}
```

This might be a bit overwhelming at first, but read it slowly and carefully and you should have no problems.

The `= '\0'`s after `strncpy` or `scanf` - these function don't implicitly null-terminate strings, so we have to do that manually - you might get away without doing it a few times, but in the long run it'll get back to you eventually. Stay safe and make it a habit.

Everyone else: if you spot any errors, let me know - it's late and I'm tired.

Regarding your questions in the comments:

1) Why am I starting at 1 in the `for` loop?
Because I'm later referring to `list[j - 1]`, and with `j` set to the value of `i` (initially), it can't be less than `1` or we'd be using negative indices. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) for a description of the algorithm.

2) How to read an entire line of string, including spaces?
The best solution would be to use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). Note that it has one quirk: it stores the `\n` character in the array as well. If you don't want it you'll have to remove it manually.

3) What is `tmp` for?
This is just a temporary `char` buffer so I can swap the two strings, as the algorithm requires. This isn't specific to strings, in general to swap two variables you need a third, temporary one (unless you opt for some dirty XOR hacks).

Comment: Okay, I am going over the code line for line to try to understand. For some reason, the program doesn't sort the list completely, for I entered a string beginning with the letter h and one with the letter a and it printed the string starting with "h" before "a".

Comment: @GenericUser01 Fixed, I forgot to decrement `j` in the `while` loop.

Comment: Wow, you are a genius. Looking at that whole while loop just makes me nauseous. How did you know to do all that?

Comment: Though I do have some questions. If array indexes start at 0, how come in the InsertionSort method we initialize `int i = 1`. `char tmp[MAX_STRING_LEN];` just creates a string for temporary storage? `strncpy(tmp, list[j - 1], sizeof(tmp) - 1);` copies the string at the given index into `tmp` and `tmp[sizeof(tmp) - 1] = '\0';` changes the last value in the array to the end char?

Comment: How would I do something typing a sentence and the program storing each word seperated by white space? So if I type, "I am learning C but it is not going well." the strings stored in the array would be "I", "am", "learning", "C", "but", etc. I figured that we would have to do an if-statement of some sort that checks to see if the next char is a space and that the input is over if the last char is a period?

Comment: @GenericUser01 I've edited my post to account for your questions in the comments. And don't worry, C does have a steep learning curve, but it becomes your second nature eventually (if you keep on codin', that is).

Comment: So if I use `fgets` I wouldn't need the for loop, would I? Since I could input however many strings I want at once and then hit enter and it would sort. So really, I would be only using `scanf` once, right? So I use `fgets` to get the whole line, but I don't want the spaces to be counted, so like the 5 strings `"I"`, `"am"`, `"new"`, `"to"`, `"C"` is derived from the sentence `"I am new to C"` How would I remove the `\n` char? I apologize for the many questions. Java is my main language, and I thought C wouldn't be too bad since it's close to Java, but clearly I was wrong.

Comment: @GenericUser01 That depends on what you want to achieve. If you want to sort actual _sentences_ - as in "I am new to C" and "I pwn at C" - then keep the loop and simply replace the `scanf` with `fgets`. Otherwise, if you're fine with only being able to compare single words, leave it as is. To remove the newline at the end of a `fgets`'d string, you could do `str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';` (bear in mind you have to make sure it contains at least 1 character apart from the newline).

Comment: I guess the better way to put this is this: if we type a sentence, the period signals the end of the input stream. So how would I get the program to run if I type a sentence that has less than 20 strings? The way it is now, we have to type 20 strings for the program to work correctly, but lets say I want to type in a sentence that has only 8 words?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95192/discussion-between-genericuser01-and-szczurcio).

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to sort strings alphabetically:

```
int s_bubblesortA(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int i , j = 0;
    char *p_1 , *p_2 , *tmp;
    while( j < argc )
    {
        for( i = 0 ; i < argc - j - 1 ; i++ )
        {
            p_1 = argv[i] , p_2 = argv[i+1];
            while( *p_1 && *p_2 )
            {
                if( *p_1 < *p_2 )
                    break;
                else if( *p_1 > *p_2 || ( ! *(p_2 + 1) && ( *p_1 == *p_2 ) && *(p_1+1) ) )
                {
                    tmp = argv[i];
                    argv[i] = argv[i+1];
                    argv[i+1] = tmp;
                    break;
                }
                p_1++;
                p_2++;
            }
        }
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

note: check this link to so my full answer to a similar post.[sort words alphabeticaly in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583221/sort-words-alphabeticaly-in-c/33583576#33583576)

Comment: How could this be changed to implement insertion sort? The class name suggests that this is bubble sort, but we are instructed to use insertion sort.